# iOS custom camera with grayscale filter + taking photos

Tags: ios, swift, filter

Hi everyone I have implemented a camera screen in my application.
I was using the `func photoOutput` to take a capture of my live preview by calling it in my IBAction outlet.

Meanwhile, I managed to look up how to apply CIFilters to my live preview using the AVVideo

But the problem is as my live preview is now running on a video session rather than a photo session after I implemented my filter

I cant get to capture the screen I am seeing.

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: 
CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    connection.videoOrientation = orientation
    let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)

    let comicEffect = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectMono")

    let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
    let cameraImage = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: pixelBuffer!)

    comicEffect!.setValue(cameraImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

    let cgImage = self.context.createCGImage(comicEffect!.outputImage!, from: cameraImage.extent)!

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let filteredImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
        self.captureImageView.image = filteredImage
    }
```

is my filter code and my live screen capture code is as follows

```
func photoOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput,
                 didFinishProcessingPhoto photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?,
                 previewPhoto previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?,
                 resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings,
                 bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?,
                 error: Error?) {
    // Make sure we get some photo sample buffer
    guard error == nil,
        let photoSampleBuffer = photoSampleBuffer else {
            print("Error capturing photo: \(String(describing: error))")
            return
    }

    // Convert photo same buffer to a jpeg image data by using AVCapturePhotoOutput
    guard let imageData = AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer: photoSampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewPhotoSampleBuffer) else {
        return
    }
    // Initialise an UIImage with taken image data
    let capturedImage = UIImage.init(data: imageData , scale: 1.0)
    if let image = capturedImage{
        // Save captured image to photos album
        // Resize image taken to the ratio of the previewView
        let originalImage = image
        let liveImage: CGRect = previewView.frame
        let liveRatio = (liveImage.width) / (liveImage.height)
        let resultingRectWidth = originalImage.size.width
        let resultingRectHeight = resultingRectWidth / (liveRatio)
        let resultingRect: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: resultingRectWidth, height: resultingRectHeight)
        //            print("@#$@#$@#$#@$@#$")
        //            print(originalImage.size.width)
        //            print(originalImage.size.height)
        //            print(resultingRectWidth)
        //            print(resultingRectHeight)
        //            print(liveImage.size.width)
        //            print(liveImage.size.height)
        //            print("@#$#@$@#$#$@#$@#")
        let topInset = -(originalImage.size.height - resultingRectHeight) / 2
        let croppedImage = originalImage.inAppCrop(image: originalImage, cropRect: resultingRect, offset: topInset)
        captureImageView.image = croppedImage
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(croppedImage!, nil, nil, nil)
        captureImageView.isHidden = false
        captureButtonView.isHidden = true
        captureButton.isHidden = true
        selfieButton.isHidden = true
        self.uploadPageViewController?.disablePaging()
        self.uploadTabBarViewController?.inAppCamButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        self.uploadTabBarViewController?.libraryButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        self.uploadTabBarViewController?.inAppCamImage = croppedImage

    }
}
```

and my IBaction calling the photoOutput function is as follows

```
@IBAction func onTapTakePhoto(_ sender: Any) {
    // Make sure capturePhotoOutput is valid
    guard let capturePhotoOutput = self.capturePhotoOutput else { return }
    // Get an instance of AVCapturePhotoSettings class
    let photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
    // Set photo settings for our need
    photoSettings.isAutoStillImageStabilizationEnabled = true
    photoSettings.isHighResolutionPhotoEnabled = true
    photoSettings.flashMode = .off

    // Call capturePhoto method by passing our photo settings and a delegate implementing AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate
    capturePhotoOutput.capturePhoto(with: photoSettings, delegate: self)

    self.uploadTabBarViewController?.titleButton.setTitle("Preview", for: .normal)
    self.uploadTabBarViewController?.previewCheckButton.isHidden = false
    self.uploadTabBarViewController?.backButton.isHidden = false
    self.uploadTabBarViewController?.cancelButton.isHidden = true

}
```

Comment: Post your Code please.

Comment: @Jake i have posted the necessary codes

Comment: @JesseSuh Did you get an answer to this? Please could you post the solution? I'm in the exact same predicament you were in here.